# Can rabbits suffer from thyroid problems?

Tags: rabbits, diseases, weight-loss

My rabbit is 5 years old and losing weight rapidly despite eating significantly. He's lost a quarter of his body weight in the last month; 2.01kg when healthy and 1.45kg this morning.

He had a dental about a week ago to burr down his teeth as we assumed that may have been the cause but he is still losing weight. Had him on critical care for the last couple of days which he's is lapping up and always seems hungry.

Just wondered if anyone knew whether thyroid issues are present in rabbits as they are in elderly cats?

Comment: Did you get lab work done? If not get back to the vet for lab work.  A 5 year old rabbit is not old.  What breed of rabbit is it? Can you post a picture?